# Rails - display integer as text variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weapon class with an attribute `weapon_type`; I'm displaying weapons like this

**listing weapons**

1. weapon_type: 1
2. weapon_type: 1
3. weapon_type: 2

how can I replace those numbers? For example, I set `1 = "dagger"` and I get

1. weapon_type: dagger
2. weapon_type: dagger
3. weapon_type: 2

Comment: If this is in ActiveRecord, then you can use `enum` (since Rails 4.1); there are also gems which do the same for older Rails versions.

Comment: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: for some reason when i set the enum the weapon_type numbers are beeing saved as strings and i get this error: 1' is not a valid weapon_type

Comment: nevermind the solution was to not submit an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS

If this is in ActiveRecord, then you can use enum (since Rails 4.1); there are also gems which do the same for older Rails versions. –  Carpetsmoker

Answer (score 0):

```
WEAPON_TYPES = {
  1 => 'dagger'
}

weapon_type: WEAPON_TYPES[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a reader in a model as, which weill return either the string type or type code for the field:

```
def weapon_type
   text_types = [ nil, 'dagger' ]
   type = read_attribute(:weapon_type)
   text_types[ type ] || type
end
```